# No output from DebugView

Tags: windows, debugging, debugview

I've installed DebugView 4.79 on Windows 7 and Windows 8 64 bit machines and a Windows 7 32 bit machine. On all of them I see no output from DebugView when starting it as Administrator. I'm trying to debug an application that uses a CLI/C++ component with ATLTRACE calls in it.

I've enabled capture events, capture win32 and capture global win32 and see nothing so I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 35):

By default DbgPrint() output is disabled in Vista/Server2008 and above. The following setting in the registry should enable the debug prints.

1. Open up the registry
2. Navigate to the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter` *or create it* if it doesn't exist
3. Add the following value `DEFAULT` :
   `REG_DWORD` : `0xFFFFFFFF`
4. Reboot

Comment: Actually, setting it to 0x8 or 0xF should do the trick according to this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551519(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `Debug Print Filter` doesn't exist on Windows 10

Answer (score 12):

IF "Debug Print Filter" doesn't exist, you should create it manually

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like there may be a [bug in 4.79](http://forum.sysinternals.com/dbgviewexe-100cpu_topic28058_post136750.html?KW=DebugView#136750).

Try rolling back to 4.76

Checklist:

- Run as Admin / Elevated privileges
- Enable Verbose Kernel Output (if applicable)
- Also, ensure that the .exe isn't [blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072359/unblocking-a-dll-on-a-company-machine-how)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure your process is running on same user or not.
EX: Your process is running in SYSTEM user. Your debug View is running on current user.

If not same user then you will need to start debug view as elevated mode.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attached a debugger to the process? If so, the output will be sent to the debugger, and you won't see them in DebugView.