# SysInternal's DebugView tool not working in Win 8.1

Tags: c++, winapi

I am not able to see any outputs through `::OuputDebugString` API in  SysInternal's DebugView tool, in Win 8.1...using code built in VS2013.
I have used this tool flawlessly in other OS like WinXP.

I am even running this tool in Win 8.1 as Admin (without any filters), but still no output. Also Capture->Capture Win32, and Capture Global Win32 options are already selected.

Comment: Did you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494300/no-output-from-debugview/12800603#12800603

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The solution of adding a key to the registry did not solve my issue. I tried a simple EXE and a DLL (containing calls to ::OutputDebugString() ) in a fresh Win 8.1 machine without installing VS2013. There DebugView was working perfectly. So its implied that VS is the main culprit here. Somehow its taking over the entire debugging scenarios. And I am unable to find a setting in VS where it will allow other debuggers also. Am I thinking in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, when a debugger is attached it is able to eat the debug messages.

Answer (score 0):

1. regedit
2. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Debug Print Filter (create if not exist)
3. DEFAULT  :  0xFFFFFFFF (REG_DWORD )
4. Reboot