# WPF Extended Toolkit Getting Started

Tags: .net, wpf, toolkit

Downloaded and installed Extended WPF Toolkit - 2.1.0
Added a reference
I can see it object explorer
I get error below on  AutoSelectTextBox not found.

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxDynamic.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type  xctk:AutoSelectTextBox}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                    <Setter Property="AutoSelectBehavior" Value="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=_autoSelectBehavior}"/>
                    <Setter Property="AutoMoveFocus" Value="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=_autoMoveFocus}"/>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But in code behind I can access.

```
Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.AutoSelectTextBox astb = new AutoSelectTextBox();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this error before because Windows blocks the DLLs because they were downloaded. See step 3 in the instructions at https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/106016

- In windows explorer Right-click -> Properties -> Unblock. Do this for all the DLLs you need or delete them and unblock the zip and extract again.

Or

- In VS remove reference to the DLLs and use the nuget package instead.

Related question: [Unblocking a DLL on a company machine. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072359/unblocking-a-dll-on-a-company-machine-how)

Comment: Late today but I will check it out tomorrow.  Thanks