# .NET Assembly loaded correctly. However calling it will crash my Application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have a C# WPF application that references an assebmly. 
It is loaded correctly since I can call `System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName("MyAssembly.dll");` in the `MainWindow()` ctor and it returns valid values like the correct path and so on.

On my development machine (Win7, x64, VS2013) I can also call all the functions of that dll. I can use it.

On my target machine (Win10, x64) the assembly is loaded just like on the dev machine. The path is valid etc.
But when functions of that assembly are accessed, the app crashes.

I am not sure how to debug this since it only happens on the target platform and the dll is definetly loaded.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you post the crash message at least?

Comment: Probably a DLL is missing on the target machine that your loaded assembly needs.

Comment: Or maybe something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072359/unblocking-a-dll-on-a-company-machine-how - Impossible to say without more detaills

Comment: I might add that the dll I am trying to add as a reference is one that I am compiling myself (http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/upload/NBIS-Net-5-0-0.zip).

Comment: I think I might be dealing with a managed C++ Project that I am compiling.