# Windows downloaded DLL Blocked

Tags: c#, dll, reflection

I have a DLL developed in C# that is used by several other apps of ours loaded by reflection at runtime, DLL is automatically deployed by Jenkins to some servers and other times installed mannually, the problem is that when I download the DLL it gets blocked and cannot be loaded at runtime. I already know that if you right click the DLL file and select properties, a unblock checkbox or button is availiable which allows to resolve the problem manually, but that solutions doesn't sufice for massive deployments, so I'd like to know if someone can suggest doing something (signing the DLL or similar) to be able to deploy it without the blocking problem

Already know that if you right click the DLL file and select properties, a unblock checkbox or button is availiable which allows to resolve the problem manually

Expected result is to download the DLL or deploy via Jenkins and have a normal operations without being blocked having **without having to do further actions since sometimes non experts have to install DLL manually**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unblocking a DLL on a company machine. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072359/unblocking-a-dll-on-a-company-machine-how)

Comment: why not make sure your deployment server is in a trusted zone?

Comment: Deployment server is in a trusted zone, thanks for your response Daniel!

Answer (score 0):

You can try running this command after the dll has been downloaded.

```
echo.>yourDll.dll:Zone.Identifier
```

Comment: That might help, but I need to void blocking at all with no further actions required if possible, thanks for your response!

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how you're downloading the Dll but if you can somehow script that as part of the download it would require no user intervention.