# C# dll I made sometimes gets "blocked" in the file properties when downloaded

Tags: c#, .net, security, windows-10, ntfs

I have a C# application that is available online for download. However, when customers download it, there is a one .dll that I created which SOMETIMES  becomes "blocked" and needs to be "unblocked" by going to the file properties and clicking unblock. The.exe won't run because this. I cannot figure out why Windows decides to block it.

I know that I can programmatically unblock the file as well by using Unblock-File in PowerShell or Streams.exe. I also know that by editing the ZoneIdentifier of a file, I can MANUALLY block files in order to somewhat reproduce the issue. I cannot however reproduce the issue by **download**. I've tried downloading my program from the website in Win10 & Win7, and have even edited the "Do not preserve zone information in file attachments" in gpedit as well, all to no avail.

My question is, **why is it that SOMETIMES my .dll gets blocked when downloaded from the internet?** **How can I prevent this block from happening, by digitally signing the dll?**

Am I doing something wrong when I package my C# solution? Is there a way to reproduce a particular **download** from being blocked?

Comment: What exactly customers are downloading and how? *"when I package my C# solution"* - what is packaging?

Comment: Windows blocks any downloaded bits to prevent security risks. So you shouldn't host binaries for download, but an installer (like MSI).

Comment: @LexLi They are .NET Framework 4.5 applications which run on both Windows and Linux. This is why an MSI in this case is not used.

Comment: @Sinatr When I **build** my c# solution, I zip the bin/release folder and put it on the site for download.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072508/1997232).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason. As far as I know, if you download any unknown dll or executable (specially in Chrome), it will be blocked and you can't use that binary file in your project until you unblock it.

**Solution**: Take dll and whatever you have in a **zip** or **rar** file. Then download and extract the zip file in the customer system. 
Even some Microsoft binaries are delivered in zip format. Consider looking at [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).